# FB.ui javascript redirect after share not working on IE8 on SSL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Help set the record straight!',
            link: 'http://www.facebook.com/nothingbeatsbeef/app_545512565475443',
            picture: 'http://cs.apps2.pixolut.com/rsrc/509309abe46cea93eefec36a',
            caption: '',
            description: 'No longer will Aussies be taunted with &lsquo;Throw another shrimp on the barbie&rsquo;. Sign the petition to get the ad that started it all remade with the RIGHT line &lsquo;throw another steak on the barbie&rsquo;.'
        },function(response){
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                 setTimeout(function(){self.location.href = '/load/preview/page/50908acbe46c03d72dcc26b6';}, 2000); 
            } else {
                 setTimeout(function(){self.location.href = '/load/preview/page/50908acbe46c03d72dcc26b6';}, 2000); 
            }
        });
```

For some reason this javascript redirect after the facebook share it doesn't work on IE8 on SSL.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried without setTimeout, redirecting straight away after posting? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this appen just using IE8 on a virtual machine.Without it is fine.